# Infragistics 12.2 WebDatePicker not displaying the Date in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, infragistics

We are planning to upgrade the browser to IE 11. So was testing all the web application whether it is compatible with IE 11.

One Asp.net 4.0 project uses Infragisitcs 12.2 and the WebDatePicker doesn't display the Date in IE 11 after hosting to IIS server 7.5. It was working fine in IE 10.

It was working fine in my local machine with IE 11. But just when it is hosted in IIS 7.5 it is not working.

Is it something related to the IIS setting.

Can some one please help on this.

Comment: Have you used the developer tools to verify that the Document mode is the same when running locally and when running from the web server?  If they are different this could be the reason for the difference in behavior.  Also how does the WebDatePicker not work, more details could be helpful for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at http://www.infragistics.com/support/supported-environments IE11 is supported when running Infragistics products 13.1 and later. It means IE11 has not been tested with older version of IG product.